# Use VBA to call R code

Tags: r, excel, vba, csv

I am working on a project that I need to use VBA as front end to call R as back end. Apparently, there is no bug warning but I do not get my output.

Based on VBA, I ask R to read an external csv file and then write a table csv as output. But it does not do the job.

Here is my code VBA and R.

VBA####

```vb
Sub RunRscript()
    'runs an external R code through Shell
    'The location of the RScript is 'C:\R_code'
    'The script name is 'hello.R'

    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim path As String
    path = "RScript ""I:\des\Perso\Xiaofei\try.R"""
    errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

End Sub
```

R#####

```
a <- read.table("German_ZCY_frombloomberg.csv",sep = ",",header = TRUE)
a <- data.frame(a)

write.table(a,"I:/des/Perso/Xiaofei/hello.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names  =FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

I do not know where is the problem since no warning happend. But I can not see the csv file "hello.csv" created.

On the other hand, if I use another R code to simply write a phrase into a text file with the following code, it works very well(VBA is able to let R do the job)

R##

```
 sink('I:/des/Perso/Xiaofei/hello.txt',append=F,type="output")
 cat('Hello World')
 var1<-5^3
 var2<-7^3
 cat('\nThe result of adding',var1,'to',var2,'is',var1+var2)
 sink(NULL)
```

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you very much,

Best regards,

Xiaofei,

Comment: Does it work if you call `R` instead of `Rscript`? Does it work if you use the console instead of VBA?

Comment: Hello Karsten. I get an error "Unable to wait untill process" when writing a R instead of RScript. I also tried console and geot the error"Error in file<file, "rt">:cannot open the connection"

Comment: followed by "Calls: read.table -> file, In addition: Warning message: In file<file, "rt">: cannot open file 'German_ZCY_frombloomberg.csv': No such file or directory Execution halted" But the file is indeed in the folder because I can perfectly run the R code within Rstudio. What do you think?

Comment: Seems like the R code can not find the input csv. In your fragment above, you use relative path specification. Does it work if you pass the absolute filename (including the path)?

Comment: I got it done finally. The problem is that when I run the code within RStudio, I do not need to precisely write the path of my csv since it is already recognized by R. But when using VBA to call R, I need to change my R code (first row) in order to tell R where the csv file is exactly. Thank you very much for the help..

Comment: You are right Karsten. Thank you very much!!! This helps a lot.

Comment: Good luck with your project!